# minimal spaning. how to solve this exrcise

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is:
Let $V = \mbox{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$. Prove that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a minimal spanning set of $V$ if and only if the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are linearly independent. 
[Hint: the contrapositive of this statement says that the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are linearly dependent if and only if $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is not a minimal spanning set of $V$]

I have tried answering this using definitions: An indexed family of vectors is a linearly independent family if none of them can be written as a linear combination of finitely many other vectors in the family. A family of vectors which is not linearly independent is called linearly dependent

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First assume that $v_1, ..., v_k$ is not a minimal spanning set of $V$.  Then, there is some proper subset, let's say $v_1, ..., v_{k-1}$, that is also a spanning set of $V$.  But since $v_k$ is also in $V$, we must be able to express $v_k$ as some linear combination of $v_1, ... v_{k-1}$.  Therefore, $v_1, ... v_k$ are linearly dependent.

Now, prove the converse, and you're done.